# Ansible roles YAML error

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Testing a basic Ansible roles setup but got an error on the first line of a role `main.yml`, I am sure it's something silly though

`play.yml`

```
- hosts: myhosts
  remote_user: myuser
  roles:
    - test
```

Directory structure

```
play.yml
roles/test/tasks/main.yml
```

`main.yml`

```
- hosts: all
  user: myuser
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - name: ping all hosts
    ping:
```

When I run `ansible-playbook play.yml`, I get the error

```
The offending line appears to be:


- hosts: all
  ^ here
```

It looks like a simple YAML parse error but if I run `ansible-playbook main.yml`, it works fine, so not sure what's going on. Any thoughts?

Comment: An (online) YAML validator will show you that this has nothing to do with YAML parse errors, but is an ansible related issue. http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: Yeah, I already know it isn't a YAML issue because `ansible-playbook main.yml` works fine, I said it looks like a simple YAML parse error which indicates that the problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify hosts in `roles/test/tasks/main.yml`. The hosts are specified in the `play.yml` file.

`roles/test/tasks/main.yml` is used to define the actions you want Ansible to perform. In your case to ping hosts, it could simply look like:

```
 ---

 - ping:
```

This will perform the `ping` action on the hosts specified in your `play.yml`

Ansible has a set folder structure it can use to break down playbooks. The `play.yml` file, specifies which hosts to target and what roles to apply along with other top level controls.

Individual roles specified in the `play.yml` file are located in `roles/X/`, there is a certain folder structure that Ansible expects. It will look for tasks to run in the `test` role here `roles/test/tasks/main.yml`.

`play.yml` is just one playbook. You can create many in the same folder and call them with `ansible-playbook`.

The official documentation has a more detailed example of the recommended [playbook directory structure](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout)

Comment: Thanks, that works but I should note that I cannot, as opposed to don't need to, specify the hosts in `main.yml`. I think Ansible is doing something basic like concatenating the 2 files and indenting the contents in `main.yml` per YAML specs. BTW, what's the `---` for? I am new to Ansible.

Comment: @Bob, you are right. I have updated the answer to be clearer and added a link to the official documentation which has a good example of folder layout. 

The --- is just part of the yaml syntax, it indicates the start of a document. It's good practice to use it, although it's not always strictly required.

 I would also recommend looking at [ansible galaxy](https://galaxy.ansible.com/) which has many example roles to experiment with.